# Mongoose - caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Why do I get this duplicate error - `Error creating new user: WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index`?

All the provided fields are not empty at all.

Schema:

```
// Declare schema
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    created_on: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Post:

```
// Create - POST
// Create the first method of the API : POST used to create a new user.
router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
    // Get values from POST request
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    console.log(req.body); // { username: 'tealou', password: 'test123' }

    // Create new user document
    User.create({
        username: username,
        password: password
    }, function(err, user) {
        console.log(user); // undefined
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error creating new user: " + err);
            res.send("Error creating new user.");
        } else {
            console.log("POST creating new user: " + username);
            res.json(user);
        }
    })
});
```

Error:

> Error creating new user:
>   WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"insertDocument :: caused
>   by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: iotdb.users.$name_1  dup
>   key: { : null
>   }","op":{"username":"tealou","password":"$2a$10$7mPGND2FRuJDGnXaVTnkru2.xsGn2Ksf8veBKur4ouD9VUNj60RaC","_id":"5786020088245d33140d6f94","created_on":"2016-07-13T08:55:28.279Z","__v":0}})

any ideas?

Comment: This might sound a little bit obvious, but are there any other users in the database with a username of `tealou`?

Comment: there is  all ready data available with same  data ..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You initially had a field called `name` in your schema, that was set to `unique`.

How do I know? Because of the error telling me so:

```
duplicate key error index: **iotdb.users.$name_1**
```

You renamed the field to `username`, but didn't remove the old index. By default, MongoDB will set the value of a non-existent field to `null` in that case.

Relevant documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field):

> If a document does not have a value for the indexed field in a unique index, the index will store a null value for this document. Because of the unique constraint, MongoDB will only permit one document that lacks the indexed field.

To solve this, you need to remove the index for the renamed `name` field.

Comment: you are right. i deleted that manually `db.users.dropIndex({"name":1})` and ran the post again then it is working like a charm!

Comment: Dude. simply awesome :)

Comment: That was some sherlock holmes level debugging

Comment: @Seinfeld run `db.collection.dropIndex()` from the mongo shell (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/)

Answer (score 5):

Dropping the collection and allowing my code to recreate it, is what worked for me.