# Is the 'name' field in mongoDB automatically an index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the error that I get: 
`MongoError insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.events.$name_1 dup key: { : "Event name" }`

Mongo says that the fields '_id' and 'name' are indexes. Here's the entry for the name field.

I removed the index, as given here: [Mongoose - caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347186/mongoose-caused-by-11000-e11000-duplicate-key-error-index) and it works perfectly now. But why was it an index to start with? **Are there fields that are automatically set as indexes?**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var eventSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    //other fields
});

eventSchema.index({ name: 0 });
mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

PS: I tried removing the index with `eventSchema.index({ name: 0 });`, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the index manually `db.events.dropIndex({ "name": 1 })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB by default sets only `_id` as an index.

When you creating collection you add index for field `name` like this `eventSchema.index({ name: 0 });`

Now coolection `Event` has index for field name.

In order to fix it you can do few things.

1) Remove index with code like @chridam suggest. Dont forget to also remove `eventSchema.index({ name: 0 });` from code. As it will create index again on next run.

2) Remove collection from DB. Remove this line `eventSchema.index({ name: 0 });`. Run code again. Now collection will be witout index.

3) Or you can make `name` index to not be unique.

Hope this helps.