# React: ".map is not a function" Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is the sample code that I received this error:

I'm getting this error via Search component. I assume , I'm overriding state.books to the object. However, can't find the solution as a junior. How should I update state.books correctly ?

`GetData.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Search from '../pages/Search';
import CreateForm from '../components/CreateForm';
import axios from 'axios';

class GetData extends Component {
  state = {
    books: []
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/api/books/').then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        books: res.data
      });
    });
  }

  addBook = (book) => {
    let books = [...this.state.books, book]
    axios.post('/api/books/', books).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        books: res.data
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Search books={this.state.books} />
        <CreateForm addBook={this.addBook}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default GetData;
```

`Search.js`

```
import React from 'react';

const Search = ({books}) => {
  const bookElements = books.map(book => {
    return(
      <div className="book-data" key={book._id}>
        <div>{book.author}</div>
        <div>{book.publication}</div>
        <div>{book.publisher}</div>
      </div>
    )
  })

  return(
    <div className="book-elements">
      {bookElements}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search;
```

CreateForm.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CreateForm extends Component {
  state = {
    author: null,
    publication: null,
    publisher: null,
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addBook(this.state);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="author">Author:</label>
          <input type="text" id="author" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <label htmlFor="publication">Publication:</label>
          <input type="text" id="publication" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <label htmlFor="publisher">Publisher:</label>
          <input type="text" id="publisher" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CreateForm;
```

api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Book = require('../models/book');

router.get('/books', function(req, res, next){
    Book.find({}).then(function(books){
        res.send(books);
    }).catch(next);
});

// Add a new book to the database.
router.post('/books', function(req, res, next){
    Book.create(req.body).then(function(book){
        res.send(book);
    }).catch(next);
});

// Update a book in the database.
router.put('/books/:id', function(req, res, next){
    Book.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body).then(function(){
        Book.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(book){
            res.send(book);
        });
    }).catch(next);
});

// Delete a book from the database.
router.delete('/books/:id', function(req, res, next){
    Book.findByIdAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(book){
        res.send(book);
    }).catch(next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

and model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// CREATE BOOK-DATA SCHEMA and MODEL
const bookSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: [false, 'Author field is required'] 
    },

    publication: {
        type: String
    },

    publisher: {
        type: String
    },

    /*available: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }*/
});

const Book = mongoose.model('book', bookSchema);

module.exports = Book;
```

Added api.js and that's model. Is there missing something ?
Added CreateForm.js and there is the place where I'm passing the new data. Is state definition wrong ?

Comment: `res.data` is not returning an array?

Comment: shouldn't be like `books: res.data.books` ?

Comment: What's happening in `console.log(res);`?

Comment: yup! please provide the structure of `res.data` object.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff res.data returning an array.

Comment: probably isn't when you POST to it to add a new book where you reset the state to the response.

Comment: @gilgamesh can you please post the contents of res?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman there is : https://pasteboard.co/HFXCRfg.png

Comment: chances are `axios.post('/api/books/', books).then(res => {` is what triggers the mutation to something other than an array, the GET on mount is fine.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your Search and GetData components. I've already tested them. I made this CodeSandbox for us to help: https://codesandbox.io/s/o4n1rlq59y In this project, I made a little bit changes to match the return data of  the test API.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú Updated code. Can you check with this latest component ?

Comment: @gilgamesh The error comes from the server-side, my friend! I've added an answer for you, please check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

### 1. Client-Side

### `App.js`

```
addBook = book => {
    axios.post('/api/books/', book).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        books: [...this.state.books, res.data]
      });
    });
  };
```

### 2. Server-Side

### `Api.js`

```
router.post('/books', function(req, res, next) {
  const book = new Book(req.body);
  book
    .save()
    .then(book => res.send(book))
    .catch(next);
});
```

Hopefully, that helps!

Comment: It works. Thanks for all contribution and one more thing :)
Should I change all router methods as like as you do ?

Comment: @gilgamesh yeah! It's totally up to you, as long as it doesn't crash your application.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because `books` is not Array. Always follow practice of checking Array and then map like.

```
const bookElements = Array.isArray(books) && books.map(book => {
    return( ...)
```

or

```
 const bookElements = Array.isArray(books) ? books.map(book => {
        return( ...) : // if not array then show some msg may b error/loader/empty list depending upon use case
```

For better solution provide more details like API reply etc

Comment: Getting this error via console.data:
error: "E11000 duplicate key error collection: bookJUMP.books index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5baddfc183aa381484e5cc62') }"

Comment: it means in your array of objects, there are two objects with same key (book._id)`5baddfc183aa381484e5cc62`

To temporary remove this error remove `keyfield` from div just for testing purpose

Comment: I added api and model if you want to look.

Comment: I think this related to mongoose. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347186/mongoose-caused-by-11000-e11000-duplicate-key-error-index

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose

Comment: I dropped out database and make a new req. still doesn't work.

Comment: try sending dummy array to `Search` component. If it works then error might be in not in react or not in `Search` component. Try debugging

Answer (score 0):

Always do conditional check when doing .map or .forEach

.map with return

```
 const bookElements = books && books.map(book => {
    return(
      <div className="book-data" key={book._id}>
        <div>{book.author}</div>
        <div>{book.publication}</div>
        <div>{book.publisher}</div>
      </div>
    )
  })
```

.map without return

```
const bookElements = books && books.map(book => (
      <div className="book-data" key={book._id}>
        <div>{book.author}</div>
        <div>{book.publication}</div>
        <div>{book.publisher}</div>
      </div>
    ))
```