# I got this Error in node js with mongoose, E11000 duplicate key error collection: domesticIndia.pans index: pan_id_1 dup key: { pan_id: null }

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, redux, react-redux

MY schema

**used by post method me this error is coming,
For which I am using mongoose with node js.
how to solve this error**

**E11000 duplicate key error collection: domesticIndia.pans index: pan_id_1 dup key: { pan_id: null }
While I have not made any collection named pans. I have checked this well**

> My Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const panSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    areaoffice: {
        type: String,

    },
    aocode: {
        type: String,

    },
    ao: {
        type: String,

    },
    range: {
        type: String,

    },
    aonumber: {
        type: String,

    },
    application: {
        type: String,

    },
    old_pan: {
        type: String,

    },
    category: {
        type: String,

    },
    applicant: {
        type: String,

    },
    firstname: {
        type: String,

    },
    middlename: {
        type: String,

    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,

    },
    ffirstname: {
        type: String,

    },
    fmiddlename: {
        type: String,

    },
    flastname: {
        type: String,

    },
    mfirstname: {
        type: String,

    },
    mmiddlename: {
        type: String,

    },
    mlastname: {
        type: String,

    },
    cardHolder: {
        type: String,

    },
    dob: {
        type: String,

    },
    contect_number: {
        type: String,

    },
    email: {
        type: String,

    },
    proofid: {
        type: String,

    },
    proofadd: {
        type: String,

    },
    proofdob: {
        type: String,

    },
    gender: {
        type: String,

    },
    adhar_number: {
        type: String,

    },
    address_f: {
        type: String,

    },
    address_v: {
        type: String,

    },
    address_p: {
        type: String,

    },
    address_divi: {
        type: String,

    },
    address_d: {
        type: String,

    },
    state: {
        type: String,

    },
    pin_code: {
        type: String,

    },
    image: {
        type: String,

    },
    sig: {
        type: String
    },
    pdf: {
        type: String
    },
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = Pan = mongoose.model('pan', panSchema)
```

> post method code

```
// @route    POST pan/newpan
// @desc     Create a post
// @access   Private
router.post(
  '/newpan',
  [
    auth,
    [
      check('areaoffice', 'Area Office is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('aocode', 'aocode is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('ao', 'Ao is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('range', 'Range is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('aonumber', 'AO number is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('application', 'Application Type is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('old_pan', 'Old Pan Type is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('category', 'Category Type is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('applicant', 'Applicant Type is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('firstname', 'First name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('middlename', 'Middle Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('lastname', 'Last Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('ffirstname', 'Father first Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('fmiddlename', 'Father Middle Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('flastname', 'Father Last Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('mfirstname', 'Mother First Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('mmiddlename', 'Mother Middle Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('mlastname', 'Mother Last Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('cardHolder', 'Card Holder Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('dob', 'Date of Birth is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('contect_number', 'Contact Number is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('email', 'Email is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('proofid', 'Id Proof is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('proofadd', 'Id Address is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('proofdob', 'Id Date of Birth is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('gender', 'Gender is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('adhar_number', 'Adhar Number is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('address_f', 'Address is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('address_v', 'Address is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('address_p', 'Post office Address is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('address_divi', 'Address of Division is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('address_d', 'Address of Dist. is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('state', 'State is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('pin_code', 'Pin Code is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
    ]
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
      const user = await users.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
      let image = req.files.image;
      let pdf = req.files.pdf;
      let sig = req.files.sig;
      const newPan = new Pan({
        areaoffice: req.body.areaoffice,
        aocode: req.body.aocode,
        ao: req.body.ao,
        range: req.body.range,
        aonumber: req.body.aonumber,
        application: req.body.application,
        old_pan: req.body.old_pan,
        category: req.body.category,
        applicant: req.body.applicant,
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        middlename: req.body.middlename,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        ffirstname: req.body.ffirstname,
        fmiddlename: req.body.fmiddlename,
        flastname: req.body.flastname,
        mfirstname: req.body.mfirstname,
        mmiddlename: req.body.mmiddlename,
        mlastname: req.body.mlastname,
        cardHolder: req.body.cardHolder,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        contect_number: req.body.contect_number,
        email: req.body.email,
        proofid: req.body.proofid,
        proofadd: req.body.proofadd,
        proofdob: req.body.proofdob,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        adhar_number: req.body.adhar_number,
        address_f: req.body.address_f,
        address_v: req.body.address_v,
        address_p: req.body.address_p,
        address_divi: req.body.address_divi,
        address_d: req.body.address_d,
        state: req.body.state,
        pin_code: req.body.pin_code,
        image: image.name,
        pdf: pdf.name,
        sig: sig.name,
        imagepath: image.tempFilePath,
        username: user.username,
        avatar: user.avatar,
        user: req.user.id
      });

      image.mv(`./client/public/panImages/${image.name}`, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'something Error' });
        }
      })
      sig.mv(`./client/public/panImages/${sig.name}`, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'something Error' });
        }
      })
      pdf.mv(`./client/public/panImages/${pdf.name}`, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'something Error' });
        }
      })
      const pan = await newPan.save();
      res.json({ panData: pan, msg: 'Pan Created' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38347579/6467056), it seems you had a `pan_id` field that was `unique` and was removed, but the index wasn't removed.

On the mongo shell, you can remove the index using:

```
db.pans.dropIndex({"pan_id":1})
```